# wc_get_product_terms returns empty array in Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

In Woocommerce 3.3.4, I have a variable product with two attributes (pa_size and pa_color). I have just one combination of those two attributes with the following data:

```
"attributes": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Size",
        "option": "1"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "color",
        "option": "Blue"
    }
]
```

However, when I call the `wc_get_product_terms( 13174, "pa_size" );` where the id is the variation id of the product, it returns an empty array. In all other cases, it does return the term. Any idea how to debug it?

**Edit:**
If I use another variation ID from a product with more than one variation, I do get a result like this `["XL"]` from the above code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Product attributes in product variation are stored in database as **post meta data**, but **not as a post term**.
To get a product attribute value you will need to use `WC_Product` method `get_attribute()` instead. You will get a term name (string):

```
$taxonomy   = 'pa_color'; // The product attribute taxonomy
$product    = wc_get_product( $product_id ); // Get the WC_Product object

$label_name = get_taxonomy( $taxonomy )->labels->singular_name; // The taxonomy label name

$term_name  = $product->get_attribute( $taxonomy ); // The term name 

$term       = get_term_by( 'name', $term_name, $taxonomy ); // The WP_Term object
```

> The "product_variation" post type dont handle any taxonomy or custom taxonomy by default

Comment: Then why do I get results if I use another variationID from a product with more than one variation? It's too strange and confusing.

Comment: @Tasos I don't get similar things like… so I don't know why…

Comment: I used your way now and it works. So, I can just abandon the old one. Thank you

Comment: @Tasos "product_variation" post type dont handle any taxonomy or custom taxonomy by default…